# What's the [problem-solving] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tagging, problem-solving

here are 358 questions tagged [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving).

> **Question**: What's the [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) tag for?

The questions with this tag seem wildly varied.  By the looks of things, it's mainly added to questions haphazardly.

*Update*:  The above question is a duplicate of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3222, although I think this tag has been misused since then.  Since there's no answers thus far I'll add some follow-up questions.

> **Question**: Do we actually need a [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) tag?

And if we do need this tag:

> **Question**: Can we make a sensible tag wiki for it?

Comment: Related: [which questions falls under the tag 'problem-solving'?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3222/75064)

Comment: Thanks for that.  For some reason I totally missed that question.  By the looks of things, it might be time for a tidy-up of this tag.

Comment: To me it is rather unclear what this tag is for. [Tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/problem-solving/info) and tag-excerpt might help users to use this tag correctly, but they are empty.

Comment: Combatting the tag once more [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19708/43288)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I propose to delete the tag. There are other tags that can be used in its place, as appropriate: [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy), [contest-math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-math), [puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle), or [recreational-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-mathematics).

One can imagine that the tag was meant for abstract problem solving techniques in the style of *How to Solve It* by Pólya. But it's hard to come up with many SE-suitable questions along these lines. They would fall under [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question), I guess.

Comment: I think problem-solving is a better tag for contest-style math than contest-math, as the latter doesn't obviously include questions not actually from contests.

Comment: @NoahSnyder On the other hand, problem-solving does not obviously exclude questions that are not in contest-style. So it gets used by people who know that they have a math problem to be solved, and little else. Contest-style math which is not for contest can be tagged recreational-mathematics.

Comment: To me recreational-mathematics means stuff like what you'd find in Martin Gardner books, which is about as far from contest-style math as you can get.

Answer (score 8):

Tag wiki says:

> Use this tag when you want to determine the thinking that is needed to solve a certain type of problem, as opposed to looking for a specific answer to a question.

Users do: [put this tag on anything but that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving). "I have a problem that needs solving, so [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) it is." There are 1410 questions with this tag, some of which have no other tag.

This tag is less than useless. Sure, the users with 5-digit reputation can talk about what *they* think the tag could be about. These opinions matter little; the actual usage is determined by those with 1 reputation. And they have determined that this is a tag to be slapped on questions at random.

Answer (score 0):

This was running out of space as a comment.

For me "contest-math" is a problem from a contest. I think problem-solving is different - "I have encountered this situation and I can formulate it as a question" - a lot of the time this will be in the context of a particular field of study.

But wouldn't "problem solving" apply to a modern-day equivalent of the Goldbach Conjecture (or even FLT or Riemann Hypothesis - stuff which hasn't been asked before and might be trivial, but possibly isn't) - "does anyone out there know how to do this?"

There is a difference for me between the questioner (who might not know the whole field), and the question. The "problem-solving" tag might be helpful to the questioner, even if it is not perfect for the question.