# Tag management 2015

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Tags need a regular cleanup. This is a customary thread for tag synonyms etc.

Rules of the game are basically [the same](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12485/):

- post your suggestion as an answer here if you see

  - a particularly bad tag (a rule of thumb: «if I can't imagine a person classifying a tag as either interesting or ignored, I'm getting rid of it»),
  - a tag that should be a synonym of an existing one,
  - a tag that used for two or more completely unrelated things,
  - a need to create a new tag;
- upvote/downvote/comment as your agree/disagree with suggestions (so please post different suggestions in separate answers);
- let's wait a couple of days before implementing a suggestion;
- after the problem described in an answer is resolved, please edit it to say so.

(Of course if a proposal requires an extended discussion you can post it as a separate question.)

Comment: A possible tool for finding not-so-great tags: [Tags by percentage closed](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/343303/most-closed-tags).  I hypothesize that some tags, by their mere existence, encourage poor and/or offtopic questions; this query attempts to sort tags by badness of questions.

Comment: @apnorton [I guess great minds think alike!](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/282074/tags-with-most-closed-question-percentage) Though mine is a horrible SQL mess (I think because I also wanted to have the overall % of closed questions, I don't remember).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I swear I searched before writing mine! :P

Answer (score 18):

I don't understand intended usage of [integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integers). Perhaps it should be either made a synonym of [elementary-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory) or just removed.

(Tag-wiki explains things like «The letter Z comes from the German word "Zahlen" which means "numbers".» but doesn't help much.)

Upd. Many questions tagged 'integers' are obviously in need of *manual* retagging, I'm afraid.

---

> I don't think it hurts to have them

IMO it does hurt (well, a little). Such tags lead to 'hash-tagging' questions (in the spirit of... I don't know... «How to prove that triangular number $>1$ can't be a square? #integers #square #triangle #proof-technique») **instead** of using correct tags like (elementary-)number-theory etc (corresponding to... areas of expertise, I'd say).

(All this doesn't apply to [real-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-numbers) — which looks like a reasonable tag to me.)

Comment: I would remove that tag; various question are not number theory.

Comment: There are also (natural-numbers), with a similar problem. Some questions belong to elementary-number-theory, some belong to logic.

Comment: @quid  Removing the tag manually is a fair bit of work. Removing automatically involves SE staff, which is  probably warranted only when the tag is explicitly problematic. This one   looks slightly weird, but then again: how would you tag a question about a puzzle SIX+SEVEN=EIGHT or some such? (puzzle) and (integers) seems reasonable in such a case. My suggestions: (1) make (natural-numbers) a synonym of (integers); (2) edit the excerpt to indicate that the tag should not be used by itself; (3) retag the questions where it is used by itself.

Comment: @Behaviour Some of puzzles like this should be, perhaps, tagged (elementary-number-theory) (and some, perhaps, should not). In any case, I don't see how having a tag (integers) on such puzzles is helpful. To me it sounds like having a tag 'plus-sign' for puzzles that, well, contain a plus sign [and are difficult to categorise otherwise].

Comment: No, moderators cannot blacklist ([status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125812/259867)) or even mass-remove ([no-status](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124504/259867)). As for second point, I do not argue that it's  helpful, but rather "not harmful".

Comment: @Behaviour BTW, do you see any real questions that can't be adequately tagged w/o (integers)? I've skipped through the list and it seems that most (?) in fact should be (elementary-number-theory) and the rest — everything like (induction), (algebra-precalculus) etc.

Comment: @Behaviour the tag "as is" seems like pure noise to me; I just browsed again the questions, there is not even much like a pattern to that list. But I do not insist it is deleted. The main point of my comment was to signal that it should *not* be synomised/merged into ENT.

Comment: @Behaviour Since you have mentioned ([tag:natural-numbers]), I'll add a link to a [discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/conversation/natural-numbers-tag). It was suggested there that this tag could be used for what I would call *foundational issues*. (For example, set-theoretical definition of natural numbers.)

Comment: @Martin Maybe you could thing about better name for such tag (for found. issues)? I'm sure a tag named (natural-numbers) _will be_ misused, no mater what we decide here (or even write in tag wiki).

Comment: @GrigoryM I am just reporting an older discussion. (If some tags have been discussed before we should not ignore that.) In any case, this is only marginal issue here, the post was about (integers). If further discussion is needed, let us continue [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19381839#19381839).

Comment: I have always seen the specific tags (rational-numbers), (real-numbers), (integers) and (natural-numbers) as being appropriate for questions about the properties of those structures specifically.  For instance, a question regarding the countability of the rational numbers might belong in (rational-numbers) because it is a question about that specific set, as would a question on how to define the rational numbers.  One similarly might use (natural-numbers) for a question like "what subsets of the natural numbers are closed under addition"?  Granted, the tags don't seem all that (contd)

Comment: (contd) illuminating or helpful, but I don't think it hurts to have them, and if some amateur mathematician were particularly interested in understanding one of these sets of  numbers they might find the tags useful.

Comment: Note that there are a few questions tagged with only [integers](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/61211?tag=integers) or [natural-numbers](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/61211?tag=natural-numbers)

Answer (score 16):

> **Resolved**

I don't care too much for [homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homomorphism).

- It lumps together questions about homomorphisms in different algebraic structures, which work quite differently, in general. Therefore, few users will find it convenient to ignore or favorite.
- The tag for each of these algebraic structures necessarily includes questions about homomorphisms between those structures. Questions about module homomorphisms, for example, would be better with just [modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules).  [homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homomorphism) doesn't really add anything.

I think we should blow it up.

Comment: On a related note: [This post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/tag-cleanup-2014/16975#16975) suggests to merge it with ([tag:morphism]).

Answer (score 14):

> **Resolved.** The tag [span](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/span) is now [synonym of linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/linear-algebra/synonyms).

I also suggest a removal of the tag [span](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/span). It isn't really that meaningful to warrant its own tag. Often in linear algebra, we are considering spans of vectors implicitly. If the tag was being applied correctly, a large portion of the questions concerning linear algebra would be tagged [span](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/span).

Comment: This could be also solved simply by making ([tag:span]) synonym of ([tag:linear-algebra]). (After we make sure that it does not contain post from other topics.)

Comment: For sure. I think that's a good option (just to prevent the tag from being created again, unnecessarily).

Comment: Once upon a time, I argued for the tag should not be synonymized to (linear-algebra) because it also comes up in (functional-analysis). But I no longer hold that view; it turns out that users asking (functional-analysis) questions don't use this tag, whether or not their problem involves span. So, I support making it a synonym of (linear-algebra).

Comment: @Fundamental Makes sense. I can understand your initial viewpoint but I think users asking functional analytic questions on average use more descriptive tags than one as general as [tag:span].

Comment: I've suggested that ([tag:span]) be made a synonym of ([tag:linear-algebra]).

Comment: I will add a link to the page where users can vote on this synonym: http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/linear-algebra/synonyms (Perhaps you might edit the information that you have suggested the synonym into your post. If you find it useful, you could also add this link. In this way, the information that the users can vote on the synonym will be visible to more users.)

Comment: *Sigh* my upvote seems to be the only one the suggested synonym has.

Comment: @MiceElf Oh well. I've suggested a handful of tag obliterations over the last couple of years. Nothing ever came of it, despite being well-received.

Answer (score 11):

I made a [meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18860/why-do-we-have-separate-complex-integration-and-contour-integration-tags) a while ago about having separate tags for [complex-integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-integration) and [contour-integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contour-integration). Based on their use, it seems like they are almost always used in the same context and their tag wikis are almost the same as well. While not all complex integration is about contour integration, e.g. area integrals, it is almost always the case in practice and on this site. [contour-integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contour-integration) was created over two years ago whereas [complex-integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-integration) was created just a few months ago. As a result I think that [complex-integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-integration) should be deprecated or made a synonym of [contour-integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contour-integration). Based on the response contained therein, I think this is a reasonable course of action.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/contour-integration/synonyms) is the tag synonym page on which this can be voted.

Comment: The class of problems about area integrals seems to suggest potential trouble with a synonym. Is there a [tag:complex-area-integrals] type tag for these? Has there not been enough questions to warrant one?

Comment: I agree - [tag:complex-integration] should absolution be made a synonym of [tag:contour-integration].  While some people might argue that contour integration may be performed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I would say that is rather path integration or line integration.  Contour integration seems to be a moniker reserved for the complex plane and would thus encompass all of complex integration.

Answer (score 11):

[art](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art), really?

What is it good for? Do we really need it?

Comment: Absolutely nothing!

Comment: I actually think that this _could_ be a viable (if little used) tag, but as it is currently used it is not. "Examples of pretty mathematical pictures" questions shouldn't be asked at all, and questions about visualising mathematics likely shouldn't be in this tag. But questions concerning the connection between some piece of art and mathematical concepts could very well be worthwhile. A first step might be to go through the tag and cull what should be culled, and see what's left.

Comment: @Art: We already have [tag:visualization] for that sort of questions. But I'm not surprised to see you support a tag named after you... :-P

Comment: *At the same time on a site close by:* [math-and-art](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/math-and-art) (created two days ago).

Comment: @quid: That question has nothing to do with art either.

Comment: My comment is not an endorsement of these tags.  I merely found the temporal coincidence amusing. (If you'd delete the tag on MO I for one would be happy.)

Comment: I don't see (visualization) as a superset of (art). Of the questions currently tagged (art) I think only five ([one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/448461), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/614474), [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/950875), [four](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/46696), [five](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/19400)) are legitimately about math and art. Of those I think only the first two are really suitable for the site. The first is certainly not about (visualization). (So IMO it would be a tiny tag.)

Comment: @Art: You said "and questions about visualising mathematics likely should be in this tag."

Comment: No I didn't. Your mind must be playing tricks on you.

Comment: @Art: I must have been dazzled by your shiny diamond.

Comment: I see this as being similar in usage to [tag:reference-request], but merging it into that would obviously not be good for searchability. Somebody wants to see beautiful art about a specific mathematical subject, I wouldn't call that off-topic. (Actually I've dang-near talked myself into asking [tag:big-list] in the process of writing this comment.) In other words, my vote is for keeping [tag:art].

Comment: A tag that is used appropriately in only 2 questions out of 10 is probably not worth having.

Answer (score 11):

> **Resolved:** Shog9 has burninated this tag.

Let's as [an upvoted answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2657/) to the old thread and comments here suggest

remove [intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intersection)

it's used for questions from «why intersection of two ideals is an ideal» to «how to compute this area of intersection using integral»; as Najib Idrissi puts it

> I don't think there should be tags "intersection" or "union" at all. These two operations appear literally everywhere in mathematics, so it's hard to restrict the tag to a single field. And I have a lot of trouble imagining someone looking specifically for questions about intersections or unions regardless of what is being intersected or united.

Comment: Finally, I can upvote my own answers! :-)

Comment: Minor update: At this moment, every question tagged [intersection] is also tagged with additional tags. So the tag is ripe for destruction.

Answer (score 10):

> **Resolved**

List of reasonably upvoted (+5 or more) but not yet implemented suggestions from «Tag management 2014»:

- [quadratics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratics) → [quadratic-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratic-equation) (or [quadratic-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratic-equation) → [quadratics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratics))
- [moment-generating-funcion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moment-generating-funcion) (note 'funcion')
- [algebraic-closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-closure) → [field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-theory)

Comment: All three issues mentioned in this post seem to be resolved now: [1](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13138), [2](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13731), [3](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12591).

Answer (score 9):

> **Resolved:** [group-homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-homology) was merged into and made a synonym of [group-cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-cohomology).

We have two tags, [group-homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-homology) and [group-cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-cohomology). Given the recent fate of [homology-cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homology-cohomology) and the fact that [group-homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-homology) only has 3 questions, I suggest merging both into [group-cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-cohomology) (since (group-homology-cohomology) is a bit of a mouthful), possibly making [group-homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-homology) a synonym of [group-cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-cohomology).

Comment: I said the word homology a lot in this post.

Comment: Similar thing was done with tags (homology) and (cohomology), see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/tag-cleanup-2014/12500#12500).

Comment: How about merge and rename as group-(co)-homology?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Tag names cannot contain parentheses. They consist of letters, numbers, and symbols `+ # - .`

Comment: Oh, well.${}{}$

Comment: Maybe (group-co-homology), then?

Comment: I support merging into [tag:group-cohomology]. I have always heard group theorists refer to the topic as "group cohomology," even when they're talking about homology; it's just what the discipline is called.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Given how uncontroversial this has been, I think you can just go ahead and do it (I don't know if that entails much work).

Comment: @najib I've been away from my laptop this week for new years, but I'll do so when I get back, if another mod hasn't by then. (Mod tools are a bit difficult on my phone.)

Comment: Okay, it's done.

Answer (score 9):

[grobner-generators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grobner-generators) and/or [groebner-basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/groebner-basis)?

I think the first should be deleted (and replaced by the second) as contained (and less used, here and in the mathematical practice) into the second.

Comment: The (grobner-generators) tag has both [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/721781/revisions) and [tag-exceprt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/721782/revisions). They could be used for (groebner-basis) tag, which has the empty tag-wiki at the moment.

Comment: Other possibility would be making (grobner-generators) a synonym of (goebner-basis). (Perhaps with the lattter as the master tag.) This would eliminate need for manual retagging.

Comment: Perhaps make [tag:grobner-basis] a synonym of [tag:groeber-basis]. Someone typing `gro...` with the intention to add [tag:grobner-basis] will usually see tag suggestions involving the word `group`, but soon enough a `b` will be written, hiding the [tag:groebner-basis] tag suggestion and causing the user to add a [tag:grobner-basis] tag. Same problem with "mobius-..." vs "moebius-..."

Answer (score 9):

> **Update:** The suggested tag synonyms [lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcm) ⇒ [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility) and [least-common-multiple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/least-common-multiple) ⇒ [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility) have been withdrawn. See [my answer here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20958) for related goings-on.

---

EDIT3: There is now a separate post discussing these tags: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20664/on-gcd-and-greatest-common-divisor-and-other-similar-tags

So if these tags are discussed further, it should be done there.

---

The tag [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) is already
[synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/divisibility/synonyms) of [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility).

It seems logical that the tag [least-common-multiple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/least-common-multiple) should also be a synonym. (And maybe also [lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcm) could be created and added to the synonyms; so that some user does not create this tag as a separate tag in the future.) As I do not have sufficiently high score in [divisbility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisbility) to suggest a synonym, I am posting this suggestion here.

The recent revisions of (least-common-multiple) [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1081126/revisions) and [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1081125/revisions) specifically mention that the notion of lcm exists not only for integers but also in rings. (And that the tag is also suitable for this usage.) I don't think this should cause a problem, since rings are also mentioned in the [tag-wiki for divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/241865/revisions). (Although it not explicitly mentioned at the [current version of tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/241866/revisions).) Note that the tag-wiki for divisibility explicitly mentions both gcd and lcm.

EDIT: [quid added this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/19403?noredirect=1#comment71202_19387) to the suggested synonyms. So it is now possible to vote on these synonyms [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/divisibility/synonyms).

EDIT2: The [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd) tag was made a synonym of [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility) as a result of this discussion: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/on-the-gcd-tag.
In this post I merely suggested that [lcm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lcm) should be treated similarly as [gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gcd).
If (gcd) being synonym of (divisibility) seems problematic to some users (as the comments suggests), it should be probably discussed in a separate thread. (I am not sure what happens to the questions tagged by the synonymous tags if a tag-synonym is removed from the system. And a synonym definitely should not be removed without discussing such step first.)

Comment: I proposed the synonyms. (On the after-thought: it would even be worse fo gcd if it were a problem. There is even a specific notion of domains where one has a gcd, creatively called gcd-domain.)

Comment: Thanks! I should point out that the tag (gcd) was previously discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/on-the-gcd-tag). (The accepted answer is the suggestion to create the synonym.)

Comment: The gcd tag should not be a synonym of divisibility. Many problems on divisibility have little to do with gcds and lcms (which need not even exist in general domains).

Comment: @BillDubuque Tag synonyms are asymmetric. (gcd) is remapped to (divisibility), which is its master tag. Not conversely.

Comment: @Fundamental Yes, but so what?

Comment: @BillDubuque As I pointed out, there was a separate discussion on this tag. I posted there [an answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/on-the-gcd-tag/11014#11014) suggesting to keep gcd. That answer got total score 2 (+3/-5).

Comment: @Fundamental I have yet to see any cogent argument for mapping gcd/lcm to divisibility. This makes it much more difficult to use tag-related tools to refine to problems on gcd/lcm. Note that one cannot always search on "gcd" since it is frequently denoted namelessly, i.e $\,(a,b) := \gcd(a,b)$ is in widespread use.

Comment: Whatever is done I think the final result should have some symmetry. That is, having "gcd" as synonym yet not "lcm" seems weird, especially as "gcd" is the in my perception more wide spread notion. I am somewhat skeptical of having very many tags. As a compromise, what about a joint "gcd-lcm" tag? @BillDubuque what do you think?

Comment: @BillDubuque I have posted a [new question on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20664/on-gcd-and-greatest-common-divisor-and-other-similar-tags) to discuss fate of the (gcd) tag. Since you have mentioned in comment, that you do not think they should be synonyms, I though that it would be good idea to let you know about the new question.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the tip. But nowadays I prefer not to waste any further time on meta matters. MSE is now past the SE point of no return (inmates running the asylum).

Comment: @BillDubuque Even if you decided to stop your activity on meta, you might at least upvote quid's answer, which suggest basically the same thing as what you said in the above comment -  that (gcd) and (divisibility) should be two separate tags. (But maybe you have already upvoted it.)

Answer (score 9):

> **Resolved**: [taylor-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taylor-series) is now a synonym of [taylor-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taylor-expansion)

I think that the tags [taylor-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taylor-expansion) and [taylor-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taylor-series) should be synonyms. (The latter is probably relatively new. It is still shown in the [list of the new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) and it contains only 17 questions at the moment.)

EDIT: Users with sufficient reputation in the [taylor-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taylor-expansion) tag can vote for (or against) this synonym [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/taylor-expansion/synonyms).

Comment: Well it has 78 questions now...

Answer (score 8):

In accordance with [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/do-we-need-the-self-learning) and the responses there, I suggest:

- Delete [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning); retag questions actually about the process of self-learning as [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) (this already has [positive support](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18972) on the other thread).

*[other suggestion moved to a separate answer]*

Comment: [related discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/496/) (started in 2010, but last answer 04.2014)

Comment: I'm not sure I like the second suggestion — (teaching) has very clear meaning [even if it's sometimes misused], distinct from (education) [which is much more loose]

Comment: Splitting (education) into (teaching) and (learning) seemed like a good idea — but now I see that, say, 'What parts of a pure mathematics undergraduate curriculum have been discovered since 1964?' is (education) but neither (teaching) nor (learning)...

Comment: I've gone through and manually retagged all questions tagged *only* with self-learning.  There are too many total (self-learning) questions to retag them all, but perhaps a bit more targeted retagging (e.g., look at questions tagged both (self-learning) and (soft-question), these are likely to need to be tagged (self-learning)) and then we can delete (self-learning).

Comment: The main problem with the self-learning is that it's not clear if it is meant for "self-assigned homework" or for "where can I learn about X by myself". The latter type of question seems much more suitable for [tag:reference-request], while tagging the former with a specific flag is rather pointless in an universe where the tag "homework" is undesirable.

Comment: One thing I'm afraid would happen though is that the "learning" tag will become equally useless over time unless *strong language* is added there to emphasize that it should only be used about the *process* of learning and just *not* for any self-posed question.

Comment: It might even be better if the process-related teaching and learning tags were burnianted too. The Math Educators SE seems to fill that gap, although it seems to exclude "Math Self-Educators".

Answer (score 8):

> **Resolved**
>
> - [intuitionism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuitionism) merged into [constructive-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructive-mathematics)
> - synonym created: [intuitionism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuitionism) $\mapsto$ [constructive-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructive-mathematics)

[intuitionism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuitionism) should be made a synonym of the tag [constructive-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructive-mathematics), which should be kept.

TLDR: looking at [intuitionism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuitionism), the vast majority of tagged questions already use it as a synonym for [constructive-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructive-mathematics).

Here is the full justification:

- "Constructive mathematics" includes many approaches to studying mathematics without the law of the excluded middle, or without other axioms that constructivists may find doubtful.
- "Intuitionism" most specifically refers to the philosophy of L. E. J. Brouwer. 
  Brouwer's philosophy, besides rejecting excluded middle, had many other specific assumptions about the nature of mathematics and mathematical knowledge that are not universally shared among constructive mathematicians.  For example, [choice sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_sequence) are particular to Brouwer's philosophy.

Some mathematicians use "intuitionism" as a synonym for "constructive mathematics".  For example, when people say "intuitionistic logic", they typically do not mean anything related to Brouwer, but just any logic without the law of the excluded middle. Others are more careful to only use "intuitionism" to refer to Brouwer's position, and use "constructive mathematics" to refer to the more general program.

On this site, looking at [intuitionism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuitionism), it is already used in nearly every case as a synonym of [constructive-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructive-mathematics), with no relationship to Brouwer's work. Having just one tag for these questions would make them easier to follow. But, if we want to pick just one, [constructive-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructive-mathematics) is better for the reasons I outlined.

The tag wiki for [intuitionism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intuitionism) *is* about Brouwer's program, but it isn't surprising that people don't read that before using the tag.

Answer (score 8):

Please pluralize:

- [quiver](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quiver), and
- [comment](/questions/tagged/comment)
- [product-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-space)

Comment: Perhaps add [tag:inequality] and [tag:nonlinear-system] to the list.

Comment: I don't know about inequality. I think it's fine for it to be singular. But I do agree about nonlinear-systems.

Comment: Hmm yes [tag:inequality] is not that bad. Note that we have [tag:functional-inequalities] and [tag:integral-inequality]. Apparently [tag:inequalities] is a synonym of [tag:inequality].

Answer (score 8):

I see that [books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) and [textbooks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textbooks) are both synonyms for [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request). I think that these should be synonyms of [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation), instead.

Comment: See also related discussion in: [Why isn't the book-recommendations tag a synonym for reference-request?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20132/why-isnt-the-book-recommendations-tag-a-synonym-for-reference-request)

Answer (score 8):

> **Resolved** (tag burninated)

Burninate [contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction)

The tag is being used for questions about a proof by contradiction. That does not give much information as many proofs are. See also [this discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20180).

Comment: See also [this new discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20615/contradiction-tag-second-passing).

Answer (score 7):

Can we have a [logical-reasoning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-reasoning) tag?
Or maybe: [elementary-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-logic), [logic-puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle)

The [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) tag is intended for questions about formal logic, for instance propositional logic, first-order logic, proof theory, model theory, etc.  However, we get questions which are really about a basic or elementary understanding of logic.  For example:

- [Why do people lose at chess?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859212/why-do-people-lose-in-chess) is tagged *logic* presumably because it would be appropriate to tag it as about logical reasoning, but it has nothing to do with formal logic.
- [If the sum of four dice was 21, how many dice show 2?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096972/if-the-sum-of-four-dice-was-21-how-many-dice-showed-2) was closed for poor quality, but if it were open, it's hard to tag it appropriately.  Currently it's tagged [puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle) and [discrete-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics), neither of which seem very appropriate.  Really the question is most accurately described as an elementary *logic puzzle*, i.e. it is about basic logical deduction and logical reasoning.

I've looked through some things tagged [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) and it seems for the most part it's being used in an acceptable manner.  But it would be nice to have a tag for basic logical reasoning and logic puzzles.

(Some more examples that might benefit from this tag: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052446/how-is-the-liar-paradox-a-paradox/), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867803/i-have-found-a-dead-body-on-my-car/), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282740/combinatorics-problem-box-riddle).)

Comment: (logical-reasoning) sounds good to me (and IMHO the suggestion makes a lot of sense)

Comment: What mathematical questions (i.e. not reference requests or big lists) are not about logical reasoning? (As for the relative cleanliness of the logic tag, you're welcome. :-))

Comment: @Asaf The idea of this name is that it's for questions that _just_ about logical-reasoning — and to me this logic looks quite similar to names like number-theory or set-theory (which are obviously not just for any questions that ask to find some number or include some sets :-)

Comment: @Grigory: I still don't think it's a good fit. Either the question is about something mathematically viable (e.g. a puzzle, a game-theoretic notion, probability, etc.) or it's not a good fit for the site.

Comment: Well, I don't really insist on this particular name — but it seems that there is a need for a tag about, well, logical reasoning (including 'logical problems' in the sense of... I don't know Smullyans book — tagging them formal logic «including model theory, proof theory, computability theory» seems hardly appropriate).

Comment: Oh, and «something mathematically viable .. e.g. a puzzle» — do you really consider (puzzle) to be a good description of an area of mathematics? To me it sounds only slightly better than (question)... (And (logical-reasoning) tries to solve a part of this problem by adding a more descriptive tag to at least some 'puzzles'.)

Comment: @Grigory: No, puzzle is rarely a mathematically viable topic; but I don't see how it's any different than a logical seasoning tag. I mean, unless you're question is specifically about some other topic in mathematics, in which case it's clear that logical seasoning is not the topic; then you question is essentially about solving some puzzle using logical seasoning. It's a superset, then, and I don't see the need for adding a sub-tag. It won't cause people *not* to use [logic] anyway.

Answer (score 7):

> **Resolved**: tag removed from all questions

Someone recently created the tag [morphisms-of-schemes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morphisms-of-schemes). Do we really need a tag separate from [schemes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schemes) for this? Especially with schemes, these objects being very often "over" another scheme, ie. the object studied is the morphism $S \to S_0$ where $S_0$ is some fixed base scheme ($\operatorname{Spec} \Bbbk$ for example)...

More generally I don't think every tag about an algebraic structure should be doubled with a tag about the morphisms between these algebraic structures; why not "morphisms-of-groups", "morphisms-of-rings", "morphisms-of-graphs", "functors", "linear-maps"...?

Comment: I know there's a tag [tag:continuous] (synonym of [tag:continuity]), but students in the majority of cases study continuity before even knowing what a topology is.

Comment: I'm in agreement here. It's almost implied I think since we're often considering such maps implicitly in the subject matter.

Answer (score 7):

> **Resolved** (synonyms approved)

Could it be possible to make [convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex) a synonym of [convex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-analysis)? It's the third time in two days that I've had to correct the tags on questions: [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118644/convexity-of-matrix-inverse), [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118834/log-concavity-convexity-of-a-determinant), [[3]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118834/log-concavity-convexity-of-a-determinant). Given the tag excerpt/wiki of [convex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) and the fact that [convex-sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-sets) is a synonym of it this seems reasonable.

Comment: Maybe even ([tag:convexity]) too to cover all bases.

Comment: I have [suggested those two synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/convex-analysis/synonyms), so other users (with sufficient score in that tag) can vote on them.

Comment: I don't know if there is a huge overlap between the people who can vote for this synonym and the people who care about cleaning up tags...

Answer (score 7):

> **Resolved**
>
> - [complete-square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complete-square) renamed to [completing-the-square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completing-the-square)
> - no synonym created because I think it's unlikely anyone will try to revive the old name

Rename [complete-square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complete-square) to [completing-the-square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completing-the-square).

Reason: the name [complete-square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complete-square) is misleading and may be confused with [square-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/square-numbers). In order to make the distinction clearer it seems better to highlight that [complete-square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complete-square) refers to the *operation* of completing the square, so why not rename the tag as such?

Comment: We don't need [tag:perfect-squares] IMO. But the renaming seems apt.

Answer (score 7):

> **Resolved** (synonyms created, also for [moebius-band](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moebius-band) while we were at it)

- Make [mobius-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-function) a synonym of [moebius-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moebius-function)
- Make [mobius-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-transformation) a synonym of [moebius-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moebius-transformation)
- Make [mobius-inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-inversion) a synonym of [moebius-inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moebius-inversion)

Comment: If [precedent](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/kaehler-manifolds/synonyms) is anything to go by, moebius-* should be the primary tags.

Comment: Is there a need for these? Do people tag "mobius-xyz"?

Comment: Someone typing `mo` with the intention to add the tag [tag:mobius-xyz] will usually see tag suggestions like [tag:modules], [tag:homotopy-theory], [tag:modular-arithmetic] etc, but soon enough a `b` will be written, hiding the [tag:moebius-xyz] tag suggestion and causing the user to add a [tag:mobius-xyz] tag instead. If nobody keeps an eye on this we end up having both [tag:mobius-xyz] and [tag:moebius-xyz]. To avoid this we need the synonyms.

Answer (score 7):

[expected-value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expected-value) is a synonym of [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) whereas [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation) is not. I suggest to

- don't map [expected-value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expected-value) to [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) anymore
- make [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation) a synonym of [expected-value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expected-value)

Comment: If it's merged, I vote for [tag:expected-value] as the master, since that is somewhat less fuzzy. [tag:expectation] hints toward "What result are you expecting from simulating X?" and sounds more subjective towards that end.

Comment: Now there is a separate question about this problem: [Expectation means average?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28381)

Answer (score 7):

What is the scope of [network](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network)? Can someone write a tag wiki or at least an excerpt?

Or should we just remove it?

Comment: Burn, I say. Burn it to the ground. Then spread salt over the ashes.

Comment: Perhaps [Network Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_theory)?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: You mean http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IebbyCAU2YA

Comment: There's also [Bayesian network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network), e.g. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160193) and [Boolean network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_network) e.g. [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150116). I'd just create tags for all these to make sure the tagging is correct at least.

Comment: I will add link to [your older post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/tag-cleanup-2014/13127#13127), which also asks about (network-flow). And I will also link to [my response in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14385558#14385558) to that question..

Answer (score 7):

> Suggestion: Burninate and blacklist [differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential).

I'd like us as a community to evaluate the tag [differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential). The tag wiki suggests that [differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential) should be used in somewhat of a differential geometric setting, however much more than half the time it seems like it is used specifically for derivatives. Of course there is a connection here, but the tag is so improperly used it is almost devoid of utility. For differential geometry oriented discussion of differentials, we have [differential-forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-forms); for derivatives, we have [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives), and for nonstandard analysis type questions, we have [infinitesimals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinitesimals). These three cover the different type of question to which "differential" might be attributed so there is no use for [differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential).

Comment: An additional problem is that due to the existence of this tag, a user entering "differential geometry" in the tag field automatically gets the question tagged with (differential) and (geometry), not with (differential-geometry).

Comment: That's a very good point. I wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: There's also [tag:homological-algebra] / [tag:homology-cohomology] for these kinds of differentials.

Comment: [Ugh](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential+geometry)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Oof. That's spectacularly bad.

Comment: @NormalHuman If I understand your comment correctly, it is only relevant to [users below 1k](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). If a user has privilege to create tags, then the question will be tagged with two tags, whether they exist or not. (See also [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23443685#23443685).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak True. But users below 1K are most often the ones who don't know what they are doing in the tag field.

Comment: @Sally That's probably true. In addition to that, situation has changed since I made that comment, since now we have [warnings about creating new tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11140/warning-for-new-tags). Which means that users who are allowed creating tags will be notify if they put two inexistent tag instead of one existing tag by mistake.

Answer (score 6):

> Rename [searching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/searching) to [search-algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-algorithms)

The name 'searching' is just unclear.

Answer (score 6):

I propose creating [limits-colimits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-colimits) for [limits and colimits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)) in the sense of category theory. (Perhaps it might be useful to create also [colimits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colimits) and [categorical-limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/categorical-limits) and add them as synonyms.)

We have many questions about limits and colimits in [category-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/category-theory) tag. Some of them are tagged as [limits+category-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits+category-theory) which is, in my opinion, incorrect use of [limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits) tag. Not so long ago [colimits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colimits) tag has been created, but it was [removed almost immediately](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1310193/revisions).

See also [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21984674#21984674) in chat.

Comment: I have created the ([tag:limits-colimits]) tag.

Answer (score 6):

What do folks here think about the tag [necklace-and-bracelets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/necklace-and-bracelets)? It started in January '14 and currently 9 questions carry this tag.

AFAICT those questions are about the application of Burnside's lemma/Polya enumeration of necklaces and bracelets constructed according to some rules.

In my opinion this is too specialized, and could fall under a tag like *combinatorial-enumeration*. Unfortunately no such tag exists. The tag [enumerative-combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumerative-combinatorics) exists but from the looks of things has been synonymized/merged with [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics).

I think that combinatorial-enumeration could be a good tag, but I don't visit combinatorics questions nearly often enoug to have any kind of an informed opinion.

Comment: I like the tag, actually; it's a particular kind of combinatorial object. For instance, we also have tags for `young-tableaux`, `partitions`, `trees`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I just came across [homogeneous-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homogeneous-equation) in a new post. This seems like an unimportant tag, just like [span](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/span). Many systems of equations in linear algebra and in ODE and PDE are homogeneous equations! A separate tag for this extremely common (almost implicit) phenomenon is silly in my opinion.

Comment: Seeing [this taxonomist badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=44374S), the tag was probably created in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391754/can-we-divide-by-any-term-when-we-have-an-differential-homogeneous-equation). I have [pinged the tag-creator](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391754/can-we-divide-by-any-term-when-we-have-an-differential-homogeneous-equation#comment2421200_391754) to let them know about this discussion.

Comment: I don't think you'll be getting any sort of response from the creator. They haven't been on the network in years.

Comment: You are right. (And I should have noticed that.)

Comment: No worries. It happens.

Answer (score 5):

[finitely-generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finitely-generated) what? Rings? Groups? Modules? Ideals?

Comment: In the meantime a user [added tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1275162/revisions) to say that it is about finitely generated groups. (But there are many other context in which the phrase [finitely generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated) is used and the tag has been used for some questions which are not about groups.)]

Answer (score 5):

I think that [independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence) should be removed. And independently of that, I think that it should be blacklisted too.

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved:** [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) is now a synonym of [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education). ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/education/synonyms).)

- Make [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) a synonym of [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education).

This is suggested [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16588/).  The tag description for [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) in fact describes math education instead of describing teaching in particular, so it looks like the two tags are being used interchangeably.  I suggest [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) be the parent tag since it is used more frequently.

In the future, [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) can be for questions about math education, and [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) for questions that are specifically about the process of learning.

(In some broad sense [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) is a special case of [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) but I think the distinction between these two is useful.)

Comment: To me it seems like [tag:teaching] and [tag:learning] are good tags, and [tag:education] should just auto-migrate to academia.se.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Not to [matheducators.se]? Also, [academia.se] is for issues at graduate level and above.

Comment: Yeah, y'all are right. I did it.

Answer (score 4):

Can we also have a look at the tags on this site? (the meta site)

the so tag  [so](/questions/tagged/so) sorry don't know how to link (yet?)

and also

- Delete [seeded-questions](/questions/tagged/seeded-questions)
- Delete [project](/questions/tagged/project)
- [behaviour](/questions/tagged/behaviour)  make it a synonym of [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette)

**PS** these are tags on the meta-mathematics  site , not of the mathematics site

Comment: You can link to meta tags using  syntax similar to the one for main tags, namely `[meta-tag:name]` like [meta-tag:etiquette]

Comment: I assume you mean to delete those two?  I hope my edits were correct.

Comment: I don't see any meta.so tag.

Comment: tags like (seeded-questions) looks both rather useless **and harmless** — they can be removed but frankly I don't see the point

Comment: @Goos i ment the so tag , thanks for the correction

Comment: ok, making (behaviour) synonym might improve discoverability (both of the tag and the tagged questions); but for other suggestions?..

Comment: I would prefer keeping ([meta-tag:seeded-questions]) for historical reasons. The tag comes from the early days of this site.

Comment: I'm definately for deleting or synonymizing [meta-tag:so] into [meta-tag:stackexchange]. I've also retagged the two [meta-tag:behaviour] questions to [meta-tag:etiquette], but still suggest making the former a synonym.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested before in [What's the [problem-solving] tag for?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9623), I propose to <strike>delete</strike> blacklist [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving).
Consider its tag wiki:

> **[problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving)** Use this tag when you want to determine the thinking that is needed to solve a certain type of problem, as opposed to looking for a specific answer to a question.

while we also have [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy), which says

> **[proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy)** For questions about approaches and techniques for discovering a proof, as opposed to writing it down clearly (which involves [proof-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-writing)). Should not be used unless the focus is on the technique of the proof instead of the solution.

I agree that [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) is different from [proof-strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy), but:

- the difference between them is very small
- the name 'problem solving' is misleading and leads to incorrect tagging
- [problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving) as a meta-math tag seems to localised to encompass a significant amount of questions

Comment: [Here is a list of questions with](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/61211?tag=problem-solving) [tag:problem-solving] [as the only tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/61211?tag=problem-solving)

Comment: Another related thread [Which questions falls under the tag 'problem-solving'?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222/which-questions-falls-under-the-tag-problem-solving).
I will also add links to the revision history for [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/537867/revisions) and [tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/537868/revisions). (So that it is easier to find them even in the case the tag is removed.)

Comment: I might be wrong, but IIRC every discussion about ([meta-tag:tag-blacklist]) so far has a separate thread. (Or at least most of them.) Maybe it's worth considering whether blacklisting something is a change important enough to deserve its own thread (and, consequently, a bit more attention from the community).

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved**

Rename [cyclotomic-polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyclotomic-polynomial) to [cyclotomic-polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyclotomic-polynomials).
Rename [legendre-polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legendre-polynomial) to [legendre-polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legendre-polynomials).
This is just for the sake of consistency, since the other tags containing the word 'polynomial' are in plural too.

Answer (score 4):

> Burninate and blacklist [parity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parity)

The tag [parity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parity) has been questioned [long ago](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2622/43288) but is still in use, while I think it is not useful. Moreover the tag is being used for (at least) three different things:

- even and odd numbers;
- even and odd functions;
- even and odd permutations.

Comment: I think ([tag:parity]) should just be burninated. It's not very descriptive and doesn't really mean much.

Answer (score 4):

Is the [nilpotence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nilpotence) tag strictly about matrices, like the tag excerpt would suggest? If the answer is yes some questions need a change of tag, if the answer is no the tag excerpt should be updated.

Comment: Vote this comment up if you think the tag should strictly be about nilpotence of matrices.

Comment: Vote this comment up if you don't think the tag should strictly be about nilpotence of matrices. (I know it's crude -- low visibility and no ability to withdraw the vote, but it's better than two answers IMO).

Comment: While I think it should not be *only* for matrices, I find it not optimal it is *even* used for nilpotent groups.

Comment: @quid The tag nilpotent-groups was [removed last year](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12529).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Perhaps then the current tag could be renamed to nilpotent-elements or something like this, possibly with nilpotent-matrices as a synonym.  And the questions on groups are retagged to something.

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved:** The tag was removed.

I can't see the utility of a tag like [non-noetherian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-noetherian) created here: [Krull's height theorem in the non-Noetherian case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252327/krulls-height-theorem-in-non-noetherian-case). I can't also see why M.SE gives permission to low rated users to create new tags. (In my opinion this could be given to users rated >20k as one of the last privileges.)

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved** The tag was removed. See also the separate post for this tag: [Can we delete the [basis] tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21091/can-we-delete-the-basis-tag)

Do we really need [basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basis)?

More specifically, there are different notions of basis in mathematics, and the tag is practically useless without adding a distinction between them.

Comment: It might be a useful tag. In any case: a) If we decide we do not want the tag, it should probably be made synonym of ([tag:linear-algebra]). (As to prevent repeated creation of the same tag.) b) If we decide that we want this tag, then the tag-wiki should definitely be clarified. (For example, there are some questions about basis for a topology in this tag at the moment.) Link to a related conversation in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/basis-tag

Comment: Martin, at 30 questions and gaining, this tag becomes a big mess. Any advice?

Comment: I created [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/basis/info) which says that this is for questions for basis of a vector space. I will try to retag the questions which do not belong here and add (linear-algebra) to questions which do not have this tag. (This activity might help some other users to notice the issue.) If you prefer to get rid of this tag, you can either [suggest a synonym](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/linear-algebra/synonyms) (basis) -> (linear-algebra) and wait for enough users to vote. Or you can open a separate thread on meta, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I've suggested a synonym. It really seems like a bad tag.

Comment: There is now a [separate thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21091/can-we-delete-the-basis-tag) discussing this tag. (Just adding the link - so that if somebody comes across this post, they see the other discussion too.)

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved:** The tag was renamed.

Shouldn't [diagram-chase](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagram-chase) be called [diagram-chasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagram-chasing) instead?

Answer (score 4):

I propose to make a synonym [double-factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-factorial) $\to$ [factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorial).

The (double-factorial) tag was previously discussed here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17011/should-double-factorials-be-under-the-factorial-tag The voting on that post seems to indicate that the questions about double factorial should fall under (factorial) tag.

The (double-factorial) was removed at the time of the previous discussion, but it was recreated again. (Probably [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1415113/revisions), as that is the only question currently having this tag at the moment.) Even the [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1415117/revisions) and [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1415116/revisions) were created.

To avoid repeated creating and removing of the same tag, I proposed the synonym  mentioned above. If you have sufficient score in the (factorial) tag, you can vote for (or against) this synonym [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/factorial/synonyms).

Comment: I have also [pinged the tag-creator](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415113/incompatible-results-with-double-factorial-different-definitions#comment2902717_1415113).

Answer (score 4):

There exist [divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisors) tag, which was created for the question about [divisors in algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_%28algebraic_geometry%29). At least this seems to be the case based on the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1418885/revisions) and [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1418886/revisions). Current revision looks like this:

> For questions involving divisors, invertible sheaves and/or line bundles on varieties and schemes.

However, it is very likely that a tag with such an ambiguous name will be used by people who do not read the tag-excerpt for questions from elementary number theory (and perhaps ring theory). (Probably most of such question could be tagged by appropriately by already existing tags, such as [divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisibility), [divisor-counting-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisor-counting-function), [divisor-sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisor-sum), etc.)

To avoid these problems, I suggest to change the name of the tag to [divisors-algebraic-geom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisors-algebraic-geom) or some other suitable name. Since at the moment there are only 4 questions in this tag (three of them about algebraic geometry), this can be done manually without bumping too many questions.

(The name [divisors-algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisors-algebraic-geometry) would be probably better, but it does not fit [25 character limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain) for names of tags.)

Comment: If we must shorten it, wouldn't "alg-geo" be better, or at least "algebraic-geo"?

Comment: There are now 23 questions in the tag :(

Answer (score 3):

> **Resolved**
>
> - [graph-symmetries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-symmetries) is no more

After posting a question in [graph-symmetries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-symmetries), I realized that the tag got kind of mixed up. Any ideas how to solve this...?

Do we need 2 tags? For currently 10 questions...

EDIT: By *mixed up* it's meant that it contains question both about graphs of functions (and their symmetries) and questions from graph theory.

Comment: I'd propose to drop the tag.

Comment: By *mixed up* you mean that it contains question both about graphs of functions (and their symmetries) and questions from graph theory? (Basically a little brother of problematic situation with (graph) tag before that tag [was blacklisted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/lets-blacklist-the-graph-tag).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak exactly...

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to add the clarification to the post. (Not everybody immediately realizes what is meant by *midex-up*. It might save time of other users, so they do not have to go to check the questions to see what exactly the problem with this tag is.)

Comment: BTW there also is ([tag:symmetry]) which could be used in combination with either ([tag:graphing-functions]) or ([tag:graph-theory]).

Comment: @Martin right, sorry to everyone who wasted time, figuring out what I meant. If combining tags to classify a question is a good way, I would go with quid's comment and also vote to retag the questions and delete the tag. Or better: what if we put a remark in the tag wiki saying: "If your question addresses symmetry of graph use the combination of blablabla..." ?

Comment: What would graph symmetry refer to within graph theory? Isomorphisms or planar symmetries?

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge I would say both.

Comment: Problem with this tag is that upper level math people are going to think algebraic-graph-theory, and calc 101 people are going to think even/odd/origin symmetry.  If we map to algebraic-graph-theory we're gonna get confused wanderers in that tag, if we map to some lower level tag we're going to get belligerent graph theorists. It's only on 10 questions, so I'm propose we sweep it under the rug and pretend it never existed.

Answer (score 3):

> **Resolved** ([kkt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kkt) made synonym of and merged with [karush-kuhn-tucker](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karush-kuhn-tucker))

We have tags [kkt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kkt) and [karush-kuhn-tucker](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karush-kuhn-tucker). Now I'm not an expert so I could have gotten it wrong, but it seems to me that these two things are actually [the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions). Could the tags be made synonyms? Preferably with [karush-kuhn-tucker](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karush-kuhn-tucker) as the main tag?

Comment: Here is [post about kkt tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/tag-cleanup-2014/12719#12719) from the 2014 thread.

Answer (score 3):

> **Update:** The [fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) ⇒ [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers) synonym is no more.

(While questions that were tagged [fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) *before* the synonym was introduced have regained their [fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) tag, this is not the case for questions that "should" have been tagged [fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) while the synonym was up. These are still tagged [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers).)

---

[fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) has been made a synonym of [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers). We decided not to do so, see [Should the tag (fractions) be a synonym of (rational-numbers)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12187) and [The [fractions] tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20203). The synonym suggestion was pending for a long time already but for some reason has been approved just now.

> Please don't map [fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractions) to [rational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rational-numbers) anymore.

**Important note:** Martin Sleziak posted two answers in one of the linked discussions to count votes [for](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20843/43288) and [against](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20844/43288) the synonym. Consider voting up (not down) your preferred choice.

Comment: Here is link to [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/138050/revisions) and [tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/138051/revisions) for [fractions](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/fractions/info). (It seems that the tag-info can survive synonymization.)

Comment: I don't understand why this happened, since I think the consensus was against it both times it was proposed.

Comment: @Martin The tag wiki and excerpt does not accurately reflect the general usage of these terms (which span from  elementary to advanced level). What  is the process for revising these entries?

Comment: @BillDubuque I think you can simply change the wiki if you want; though perhaps you might want to mention the suggested edit in the tagging room first to see if anyone disagrees.

Comment: @BillDubuque At the moment, the two tags are synonymized, so if we want to edit tag-info, the synonym must first be cancelled. But in general: Every user with sufficient rep can edit them. If a user below 20k edits tag-info, the edit must be review by at least two users. However, I think it is better to discuss changes on meta - at least in cases where there is a probability that there might be some disagreement about the usage of tags.

Comment: I will add that it is not important whether the the tag-info reflects the usage of *terms*. It is more important that it correctly describes how the *tags* should be used on this site. For example, if the discussion on meta and tag-info clarified that the tag (filters) is for filters in set-theoretic and order-theoretic sense, then this tag should not be used for Kalman filters and other filters used in digital signal processing and various related areas.

Comment: In any case, if further discussion about editing tag-info (=tag-wiki or tag-excerpt) is needed, we can continue [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740). (If needed, it can be discussed even in a separate post on meta. But it would be good to search first whether there already have been some discussions related to this.)

Answer (score 2):

Currently the [primitive-roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primitive-roots) tag is used for both primitive roots in modular arithmetic and questions involving primitive roots of unity. Since these two things aren't immediately related this is undesirable. I once edited the tag wiki, adding

> For questions about primitive roots of unity, use the (roots-of-unity) tag instead.

hoping that this would help users to use the tag appropriately, but I think it will be more effective to introduce a [primitive-roots-of-unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primitive-roots-of-unity) tag.
I suggest either clarifying the [primitive-roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primitive-roots) tag (renaming it if necessary) in order to make it exclusively for primitive roots in modular arithmetic, or creating a new tag for primitive roots of unity instead, though such tag would not be of much value.

Note: previously I asked this [as a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19200/create-a-primitive-roots-of-unity-tag), receiving the following comments:

> There's a thread dedicated to tag management issues. Anyway I disagree with the creation of a [primitive-roots-of-unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primitive-roots-of-unity) tag: there is no way that someone would want to search of that tag or ignore it and not do the same with [roots-of-unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roots-of-unity). Clarifying [primitive-roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primitive-roots) is the way to go (either include both topics or rename it/edit the tag wiki to something clearer). –  [Najib Idrissi](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10014)

and

> I agree with the preceding comment. If at all the tag you propose should be a synonym of the existing one. –  [quid](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10014)

Comment: There were only twelve cases, I re-tagged them manually using [tag:roots-of-unity].

Answer (score 2):

> **Resolved**
>
> - synonym created: [covering-maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covering-maps) $\mapsto$ [covering-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covering-spaces)

I think that (covering-maps) is a good synonym for [covering-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covering-spaces).

Answer (score 2):

The [monoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monoid) tag has inconsistent plurality. I suggest renaming to [monoids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monoids).

Comment: [Relay Ted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20037/622).

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** The tag [limits-colimits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-colimits) was created by Martin. So it seems that the best course of action is now to merge these two tags, or add them as synonyms.

---

Do we need the [direct-limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direct-limit) and [inverse-limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse-limits)?

I have no opinion on the matter, but maybe those should be merged into a single tag somehow?

And if we keep the tags as they are, someone should probably write at least a tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. I haven't even noticed that.

Comment: I don't think we need these tags, just like we don't need tags like "coproduct", "equalizer" and every possible (co)limit shape one can think of -- that's way too many tags for a very limited payoff (if there's a payoff at all, I can't think of any).

Comment: @Najib: What about the recently created [tag:limits-colimits]?

Comment: I think making both direct-limits and inverse-limits a synonym of limits-colimits would make sense.

Comment: @Najib: That's a good idea. I don't have the needed reputation, though.

Comment: Neither do I...

Comment: @Najib: Well. I raised a flag asking the moderators to take care of that. So now we play the waiting game.

Comment: I've just retagged the four [tag:inverse-limits] questions, there are still 8 [tag:direct-limits] questions left (I'll probably wait a bit so as not to flood the front page).

Comment: Both tags have been removed. Perhaps this can be marked as resolved? Or do you still wish make the synonym?

Comment: @Martin: I guess we can mark that as solved for now, and if they return we can sue for synonyms further.

Answer (score 2):

Do we *really* need both [stability-in-odes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stability-in-odes) *and* [stability-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stability-theory)?

I'm honestly asking, since both these tags seem to be way out of my league. Perhaps someone better versed can make some comments. Are they even both needed at all?

Comment: Background: [Do we need more stability?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16796). In the comments, I was in favor of [stability-theory] but David Speyer pointed out different intepretations of it. Of course, most of tagging is done by users less knowledgeable than David Speyer...Maybe your answer could be posted there, for better proximity to the roots of the tag...

Comment: Tags are a [Folksonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy) anyway; if most users think that stability-theory is the way to tag ODE questions, then so be it...

Comment: I really don't know. This is way out of my water, and I'm honestly asking if we need two stability tags. If someone from the field of ODE wants to say "yes", then I'm willing to take their word for it.

Comment: I understand; My main suggestion is to move the discussion to the already-existing dedicated thread. Since it already exists....

Answer (score 2):

I propose creating the [positive-definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/positive-definite) tag and also adding the tags [definiteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definiteness) and [negative-definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negative-definite) as synonyms.

This seems to be relatively important topic and we have enough questions about definiteness of matrices. You can also notice that some users use the tag [positive-characteristic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/positive-characteristic) for this purpose. (A few examples are listed [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23250963#23250963).) Creating the new tag would prevent such mistaggings.

Suggested tag-excerpt:

> For questions asking whether some matrix is positive definite (negative definite, positive/negative semidefinite, ...) and for questions asking about properties of positive definite (negative definite, positive/negative semidefinite, ...) matrices.

Comment: What sorts of questions would be included under this tag? Would questions about a specific matrix which happens to be positive-definite fit? What about semi-definiteness? For an answer here proposing a new tag, I would much prefer to see information about how you think the proposed tag should be used. Tag-excerpt and -wiki proposals might also be valuable additions.

Comment: I'd say it is more or less self-evident that not every question containing positive definite matrix would fall under the tag. If the fact that it is positive definite is relevant, then it is a good fit.

Comment: I don't support ([tag:definiteness]) but ([tag:positive-definite]) seems pretty acceptable to me.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The reason for suggesting ([tag:definiteness]) was that it seems reasonable to have under same tag questions about positive (semi)definite matrices and negative (semi)definite matrices. So I looked for a word encompassing both of these notions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_%28disambiguation%29

Comment: Yeah I actually retract my comment. I think it's a better tag for sure.

Comment: It seems that ([tag:positive-definite]) was created [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1476826/revisions). Maybe it will survive. (In that case we can consider this resolved.)

Comment: There is now a [tag:positive-semidefinite] tag. I think it should be made a synonym of [tag:positive-definite].

Answer (score 2):

> **Resolved**: The tag is gone

What is [generalized-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generalized-functions) for?

It is often misused, and when it is used correctly it seems to be synonymous with [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory), though I don't have the expertise to say so for sure.

Comment: Yes, it would be a synonym of distribution-theory. There is a (poorly written) [tag wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/generalized-functions/info). I don't think we need this tag.

Comment: I retagged and edited those questions. The tag should go away soon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have sufficient privileges on this site to create a tag, but I think that it would be useful to have a new tag **imprecise-probability**, which I would have applied, instead of four other somewhat misleading tags, to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550331/why-does-the-natural-extension-of-a-lower-prevision-dominate-it) that I recently asked.  [EDIT: There is at least [one other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370539/lower-expectation/372014#372014) for which **imprecise probability** would be appropriate.]

Imprecise probability is a broad term for a class of concepts and methods that generalize ideas probability theory beyond real-valued probability measures.  It's most readily viewed as a way of extending Bayesian probability to reflect uncertainty in degrees of confidence, but there are uses of the idea that don't necessarily reflect these Bayesian roots.  The term covers, among other things, upper and lower previsions, upper and lower probability, interval-valued probability, credal sets, lower envelopes, and Choquet capacities (see e.g. [Fabio Cozman's introductory page](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~qbayes/Tutorial)).  There are at least three book-length mathematical treatments: Walley's classic [*Statistical Reasoning with Imprecise Probability*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412286602), Augustin et al.'s [*Introduction to Imprecise Probability*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470973811), and Troffaes and de Cooman's [*Lower Previsions*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470723777) (along with earlier works of mathematical philosophy such as Levi's [*The Enterprise of Knowledge*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262120828)).  There is an academic society with regular conferences on the topic, the [The Society for Imprecise Probability: Theories and Applications](http://www.sipta.org/).

Imprecise probability is related to ideas for which we already have tags: **probability-theory** (obviously), **fuzzy-logic** and **fuzzy-sets** (the focus is usually on different axioms), and **robust-statistics** (since these make use of sets of probability measures).  The **expectation** tag is also related, since upper and lower previsions generalize expectation.  However, none of these tags seems correct for the topics mentioned at the beginning of the second paragraph above.  I do think that "imprecise probability" is sometimes used in sense that allows it to overlap with the domains of the tags I just mentioned, but those tags nevertheless misleading for a question such as the one I asked.

Here's a possible tag description, copied from the [SIPTA website](http://www.sipta.org/index.php?id=soc):

> Imprecise probability is understood in a very wide sense. It is used as a generic term to cover all mathematical models which measure chance or uncertainty without sharp numerical probabilities. It includes both qualitative (comparative probability, partial preference orderings, …) and quantitative modes (interval probabilities, belief functions, upper and lower previsions, …). Imprecise probability models are needed in inference problems where the relevant information is scarce, vague or conflicting, and in decision problems where preferences may also be incomplete.

(Ellipses in the original.)

Answer (score 1):

the different tags for [recreational-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-mathematics)  like

- [puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle)
- [riddle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle)

and maybe more

combine them all to one tag (and make the rest synonyms)

ps how do you link to a tag?

Comment: To note [tag:puzzle] and [tag:riddle] are already synonyms.

Comment: I'm not sure to what extent (recreational-mathematics) ends up being useful, as there are a lot of things which could qualify.  But I do like (puzzle)/(riddle), which seems much more concrete.  I am not sure I would like them all to be combined.

Answer (score 1):

The [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences)-issue should not be forgotten. It has been mentioned more than a year ago in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11232 but has not been solved since.

> Rename [congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences) to [congruences-remainders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congruences-remainders) and make it a synonym of [modular-arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic)

<strike>It should be noted that congruences are in fact more generally used in algebra, whereas modular arithmetic technically only covers the integers.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

> **Resolved:** Tag has been removed.

I was going to remove the tag [gronwall-inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gronwall-inequality) from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131077/effect-of-differentiation-on-function-growth-rate) until I realized that there were [a hundred questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=gronwall%27s%20inequality) related to this inequality. I am not too familiar with DEs: do people who are think this could use a tag?

Comment: I've heard colleagues mention it multiple times and I've seen it in stochastic processes. I think it's probably safe to leave it as is. I think people who need it, it's a very good tag to have.

Comment: Right, so I guess my question is whether it is worth creating tagging those 100 questions.

Comment: Oh I see. I totally had the opposite understanding of your comment. I feel silly now. Reading comprehension is hard. I think it might be beneficial for sure.

Answer (score 1):

> **Resolved**: the tags have been deleted

These 2 tags: [graphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphic) and [animated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animated) seem to be created for just one question. Even the tag names are not math-related. Why do they still exist?

Comment: They still exist because nobody removed them. Anybody with edit privileges can edit the question to remove these tags, and they will be deleted in 24h. It doesn't look like the question is primarily mathematical in nature anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Make [regular-expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expressions) a synonym of [regular-language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-language). Perhaps pluralize [regular-language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-language).

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20129/can-someone-put-in-an-explanation-for-the-regular-expressions-tag

Answer (score 1):

[cantor-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cantor-set) has about 15 questions at this time of posting.

I don't think we need this tag at all. Does anyone have any arguments in favor of keeping it?

Comment: This falls into same category as [Klein bottle](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19858) or [Sorgenfrey line](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/some-thoughts-on-what-makes-tag-useful). We probably have a few tags about particular topological space. I think such tags might be useful. In particular, Cantor set is frequently used in real analysis. (Maybe posts about Cantor function could go into the same tag - they are closely related.)

Comment: Maybe. I'm not sure that those tags are useful either. They don't give you anything that the half-working search system couldn't give you *easily*.

Comment: I've made this argument already (@Martin linked to it), but it seems that the community's opinion (or at least, the people who browse meta) is that such tags are useful.

Comment: @Najib: Some people make mistakes. :-P

Answer (score 1):

We have a [metalogic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metalogic) tag, apparently. I think it could be either removed or merged/synonymized into [meta-math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-math).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing myself. There is a very slight difference in meaning (or at least a difference in connotation), but it is so extremely slight that most askers will simply use the word their textbook uses.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that we should remove tags like [noetherian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noetherian), [prime-ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime-ideals) and [maximal-ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maximal-ideals). They don't really help to organize. IMHO they  basically just elaborate on the content of a specific question. If someone has a question about a Noetherian module, they'll probably just start with: "We have a Noetherian module $M$..." I said "tags like", because there are probably more tags of this kind that I haven't come across. To me these  kind of tags are equivalent to using the tag "[mod5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod5)", instead of just [modular-arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic).

---

If someone knows of more tags that  elaborate on content of a specific question rather than organize, then please mention these in the comments, so we can get rid of them all in one swift move.

---

In addition, the same thing holds for:

- [multiplicative-order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplicative-order) (as mentioned already by *Lord_Farin*)

Comment: This is an extremely broad proposal. I think you should try to pin down what makes you say "They don't really help to organize. IMHO they basically just elaborate on the content of a specific question." More specifically, generally adjectives are not so great as tags, thus I think  agree  "noetherian" is not a good tag, I am not sure about the "ideals."

Comment: @quid To be fair, when a tag is to specific for a question is of course decided by an arbitrary line in the sand, differing per person. I just feel very strongly that a majority of people would agree with me on which side of the line these two belong. Also the number of followers of these tags does not speak in favour of prolonging their life span. In any case, you would surely agree with me that if they stay, they should be merged to one tag: ([tag:ideals]) (based on your very well put "adjectives argument").

Comment: I don't know. The taxonomist tag is awarded at 50 questions tagged with a tag. I have no strong feelings either way it is just mainly that the proposal feels arbitrary in its scope. What about [tag:flatness] or any number of other tags that are a lot smaller.

Comment: @quid [tag:flatness] can also go if you ask me. For the same reasons basically. But that's just how I feel.

Comment: There is now a separate question about the ideal-related tags: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23012/should-we-have-tags-maximal-ideals-and-prime-ideals

Comment: @user26857 Looking at the votes on [the new post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23012/should-we-have-tags-maximal-ideals-and-prime-ideals), there are 22 upvotes on the answer for the synonym and 9 upvotes on the answer against. So definitely more people support synonymizing these tags with ideals. So maybe you could [suggest a synonym](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/ideals/synonyms). (After all, you brought up this issue again in comments on the main and you also made clear that you are for removing/synonymizing (maximal-dieals) and (prime-ideals).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I've proposed to keep only the `ideals` tag, and remove the other two.

Comment: @user26857 Making the two tags synonymous with ideals basically does that with two additional advantages: 1) The users cannot create the two tags anew. 2) All posts which are currently tagged by any of those two tags would be now automatically tagged ideals. In any case, if you have some different suggestion from the two posted in the linked post, you can post another answer. And if needed, we can discuss this further [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/4/22).

Answer (score 1):

There are tags [l-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l-series) and [l-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l-functions). 
While there is a slight difference, I do not think we need these as separate tags. 
(Especially not as there is also [dirichlet-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirichlet-series) which could be use for questions on more "formal" aspects.)

I propose to make these two   [l-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l-series) and [l-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l-functions) synonyms. Actually, I think they could even be merged into [zeta-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeta-functions).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that we have [kripke-models](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kripke-models) available. And I think it should be merged/made a synonym for [modal-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-logic).

While the distinction has merits, much like the distinction between first-order logic and predicate calculus into two tags has merits, these tags are barely used, and it makes sense to bunch them together. Not to mention that only 4 of the current 16 questions are not tagged with the modal logic tag.

Comment: What if someone asks about Kripke models in the context of intuitionistic logic?

Comment: There seems to be a question about intuitionisitic propositional calculus under this tag. But it also has the modal logic tag...

Answer (score 1):

Why is the tag for [complete-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complete-spaces) useful?

I don't see it. I think it should be removed, although it's not as bad as the [recently blacklisted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21031/blacklist-the-completeness-tag) [completeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/completeness).

Comment: I thought I got rid of this tag once already.

Comment: We have many questions asking whether some particular metric space is complete. Tag related to this would make searching for such questions easier. (Although probably (complete-metric-spaces) would be a better name.)

Comment: @Martin: I'm a bit with Arthur on this. I guess.

Comment: @Arthur: Maybe it's time to bump the tag creation privilege to 2000? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: I'd almost suggest bumping it up to ♣+CH. ;-P

Comment: @Arthur: Since CH implies MA trivially, the only way I'd agree is if Martin becomes a moderator and make all these decisions aximoatically. :-P

Answer (score 1):

I propose creating [absolute-continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-continuity) tag. [Absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) seems to be rather important notion in real analysis. It is closely connected to the Fundamental theorem of calculus. And it is closely related to several other important classes of functions - many of the important enough to have a separate tag on this site, such as [bounded-variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounded-variation), [uniform-continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uniform-continuity) and [lipschitz-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lipschitz-functions).

We often have questions related to this notion. Just try to search for:

- [absolutely continuous is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=absolutely+continuous+is%3Aq)
- [absolute continuity is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=absolute+continuity+is%3Aq)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to delete the [analytic-spread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-spread) tag as too specialized.

Comment: I don't see why a tag used on 2 (two) questions requires any action. Not being an expert I'm also not sure if the tag is actually bad.

Answer (score 0):

Someone recently created [klein-bottle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klein-bottle). While I can appreciate the intent, I guess I don't really see the point: pretty much any question related to the Klein bottle will have the words "Klein" and "bottle" in quick succession and can be easily searched (which may not necessarily be the case for other spaces that have standard notations, eg. the projective spaces).

I also don't think the Klein bottle is so fundamental that it deserves a tag of its own, and there cannot be tag for every named, somewhat interesting mathematical object. Imagine if we had tags for the Bernoulli distribution in probability, the Monster group, the Euler characteristic or the monoïdal tricategories... At some point I think tags would become more  redundant than useful.

Comment: I think most of these arguments would also apply to [tag:moebius-band], though there's the difficulty that it's sometimes called "Möbius/Moebius/Mobius band/strip". But in general I think tags should be more like categories. So eg. [tag:surfaces] could be a better option.

Comment: i agree... i just saw 4 (old) klein bottle questions on the front page and was wondering what was going on... someone is bumping all of the questions by adding the tag

Comment: I actually disagree with this suggestion. I actually feel that highly focused tags are often better than many of our wishy-washy tags such as [tag:compactness], where it is often difficult to determine if a question really falls under the tag (and is therefore used inconsistently). At least with [tag:klein-bottle] it should be easy to determine whether a question actually is about that concept.

Comment: @ArthurFischer My point is precisely that it's so easy that the tag becomes useless: someone looking to answer questions about the Klein bottle can just search for these words. (Though maybe someone is so uninterested by Klein bottles that they want to ignore the tag...)

Answer (score 0):

The tag [multiplicative-order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplicative-order) was created.

It seems to me that this is a natural synonym of [modular-arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic).

Comment: I agree that it is a subtag of [tag:modular-arithmetic] but I would not make it a synonym, as it facilitates searching and doesn't seem too localised not to stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

The tag [algebraic-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-numbers) is created recently. Do we need such a tag? I suggest to make it a synonym of [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) (or [transcendental-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transcendental-numbers)) or just remove it.

Comment: I would rather make it a synonym of [tag:transcendental-numbers].

Comment: I just realized that my previous comment is inconsistent with the fact that we have a tag [tag:rational-numbers] *and* a tag [tag:irrational-numbers]... Something I don't really find optimal.

Comment: We'd have to ask us whether there is a significant amount of questions about algebraic numbers that are not about transcendental numbers, and vice versa. (This is the case with rationals/irrationals; e.g. questions regarding rational solutions to diophantine equations, representations of rational numbers; the topic of [tag:diophantine-approximation]). If there isn't, I suggest to merge both tags into [tag:algebraic-transcendental] or something.

Comment: I would find it possibly confusing to have algebraic numbers as a synonym of transcendental numbers; it could result in weird tagging. Somebody asking something about $Q[\sqrt{-7}]$ might tag algebraic-numbers, but this should not be related to transcendental numbers at all. If anything I would synonym it with [tag:algebraic-number-theory]

Comment: It seems that the tag [was removed](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1300546/revisions).

Comment: @MartinSleziak : Yes. Indeed I am not sure if it is appropriate to do so (un-tag that only question, so as to delete the tag)

Comment: If this is what you are asking, removing tag from all questions is precisely the way how to delete the tag: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/deleting-tags-after-being-created If you are asking whether the discussion here show sufficient support for the tag removal to go ahead with it - the only thing I can say is: Use your best judgement.

Answer (score -1):

Do we need [domain-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-theory)?

It passes the "initial Google test", and it seems to be a subset of order theory. Currently there are two questions, both written (and tagged) by the same person. And this seems like a tag that will be rife with mistagging by people who ask questions like "What is the domain of ..."

The latter is not a reason not to have a tag (just look how many do this with logic and set theory tags!), but since domain theory is not a particularly active topic on this site, it means there will be less people monitoring the tag and less people will be maintaining its correct use.

So I'm asking, do we *really* want this tag, or should we forfeit and remove it?

Answer (score -3):

> **Update.** [Martin  Sleziak's suggestion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/19060#comment69475_19060) has been taken up, and [(limits-without-lhopital)](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limits-without-lhospital/synonyms) has been made a synonym for [limits-without-lhospital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-lhospital).

Change [limits-without-lhospital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits-without-lhospital) to "limits-without-lhopital". Change tag wiki text from L'Hospital to l'Hôpital.

Comment: "In the 17th and 18th centuries, the name was commonly spelled "l'Hospital", and he himself spelled his name that way. However, French spellings have been altered: the silent 's' has been removed and replaced with the circumflex over the preceding vowel. **The former spelling is still used in English where there is no circumflex**." [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: As for tag wiki change, you can go ahead and suggest an edit yourself; they are edited by users like other posts, except there is a higher threshold for approving the edits.

Comment: I am not sure the change is needed, but having both names (as synonyms) will probably do no harm.

Comment: [Similar (Kähler)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17360/my-first-tag-synonym-suggestion-did-i-do-it-right), in the end they were made synonyms.

Comment: I will add a link to a related questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20542/limits-without-lhospital-tag-misspelled

Answer (score -3):

It was brought up in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19480/43351) as a side remark that we have both [math-software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-software) and [computer-algebra-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-algebra-systems).

It would appear to me that the latter can be merged into the former without much trouble.

Comment: To me the tag (computer-algebra-systems) seems to be more specific. For example, Geogebra, Google calculator, R and S are (math-software) but they probably aren't computer algebra systems. (judging from the very little I know about Geogebra, R or S. )

Comment: I agree with Martin. I'd say it might even depend on the question. When I'm using Sage to do computer algebra (under the hood via Maxima), that should be on topic for CAS. When I use Sage to do numerical optimization, or statistical analysis, or draw geometric figures, that's not sp much CAS but still computer algebra. So I'd say keep both tags, but in the math-software wiki, don't fix the distinction on the software alone.

Answer (score -4):

The tag [sedenions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sedenions) looks very narrow to me. [Only nine questions even mention the word at all.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=sedenion+is%3Aquestion) It seems to me that sedenions are only ever thought about when one thinks about the [Cayley–Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction).

I suggest creating [cayley-dickson-construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cayley-dickson-construction) and making [sedenions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sedenions) a synonym of this. Many (almost all) questions mentioning sedenions or mentioning the word are already about the construction ("what lies beyond quaternions?", "what do we lose when going to sedenions"... basically).

---

The case of [octonions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/octonions) is a bit more debatable: [56 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=octonion+is%3Aquestion). As far as I know octonions don't really have many more uses ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-are-some-real-world-uses-of-octonions) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678833/what-can-you-do-with-octonions)). [quaternions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quaternions) is fine for me, they are useful on their own and much more common. If this suggestion is implemented, we could have a discussion about making [octonions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/octonions) a synonym too.

Comment: I have favourited (octonions) and I'm certainly against deleting the tag. BTW citing answers to question about _'real-world'_ uses of something to prove it mathematical uselessness is downright ridiculous (can you think of many 'real-world' uses of etale cohomology or BGG-resolution, I wonder?).

Comment: @GrigoryM I cited that because the only mathematical use of octonions I know is the Hopf invariant problem, and even then it's only tangentially relevant. Anyway, maybe I should have separated the two suggestions (octonions and sedenions)? I tried to make it clear that the suggestion is mostly about the tag sedenions, but I guess that didn't work out.

Comment: Posting two suggestions in one answer is always inconvenient indeed. But more importantly...

Comment: ...to [quote](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19082/) Behaviour: «there are perfectly sensible tags (...) [s.t.] few users read or vote on posts in the tag. This does not make the tags useless; on the contrary, it helps the few users knowledgeable in those subjects find and answer the questions they are interested in.»

Comment: @GrigoryM Did you read  that part "Many (almost all) questions tagged sedenions or mentioning the word are already about the construction ("what lies beyond quaternions?" basically)." or that part "making sedenions, and even possibly octonions a **synonym** of this"?

Comment: Okay, perhaps for (sedenions) your suggestion makes sense.

Comment: @GrigoryM I edited my suggestion.

Comment: ...As for uses of octonions in topology and geometry, algebra and  number theory see John H. Conway. On Quaternions and Octonions, [Baez. Octonions](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node1.html) and (ample) bibliography there