# Smart automatic mass-retagging

Tags: support, tagging, tag-management, retagging

Is there some way to automatically mass-retag questions in a strategic manner?

I'm trying to implement [a tag suggestion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/19085#19085) which involves removing the tag [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning).
Basically, I'd like to:

- Retag all questions with [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) in addition to at least one other soft tag ([soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question), [advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice), [big-list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list), [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education), [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching)) by replacing [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) with [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning).
- Delete the tag [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) on all other questions where it appears.

I believe the result would be that, with pretty high accuracy, questions which are actually about the process of self-learning would be newly tagged [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), and questions which just have [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) appended but are really just math questions would have the tag removed.  There are too many questions tagged [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) to go through them individually.

Is this sort of thing possible?

Comment: But does this specific retagging even make sense?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, it does. Hence the positive support. If you want to know what's going on with [tag:self-learning], see [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/do-we-need-the-self-learning-tag/18972#18972) (with even more positive support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible (using usual tools, obviously somebody with db-access could do that). Moderators can merge one tag into another, but that's all, there are no additional options (except for maintaining or not a synonym). Put differently, you could just replace every occurrence (this however is simple).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I've posted two really dumb answers to this (deleted... 10k users, please don't look. `:P`).  This one should be better.

This [Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/263846/soft-self-learning-questions) I just wrote lists all the questions tagged with *only* [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) or [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) and *at least one* of the following:

- [advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice)
- [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question)
- [big-list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list)
- [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education)
- [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching)

...and *not* already tagged with [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) (since we want to replace [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) with [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning))

There are 287 such questions.  If we retag 10 a day, we can be done in about a month.  After that retag, we can delete [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) and then all will be well.

If we expand the search to also include all [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) posts that don't have MathJax, then we end up with [~500 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/263848/soft-self-learning-questions-without-mathjax).

Comment: If people really want, I could try to write a program to use the SE API to perform the mass retag with ~10 questions spread over a day over a duration of 2 months.

Comment: After mentioning the above idea to people in the meta Tavern and being told "no" about 5 times in 2 seconds, I think I'll retract that offer.

Comment: Actually, I think 500 questions is doable by one or two people if they put just a little work in.  10 seconds per question makes that just 2.5 hours total.

Comment: I agree with @Goos that it is doable, although it is big undertaking. Comparable to the removal of (algebra), where manual retagging of 700 questions [took about 5 months](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/appropriate-speed-of-mass-retagging-and-algebra-tag).