# How can we create a new tag in a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, tagging

How can we create a new tag in a Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 7):

From Help Center > Privileges > [Create Tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> **How do I create a new tag?**
>
> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> - must be shorter than 25 characters
> - must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

You need at least 1k reputation points to be able to do this.

---

I will add that you should check carefully before creating a new tag whether there already is a suitable tag.

Before creating a new tag, check [FAQ on tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/128#128) for general advice on tagging, on creating new tags and on tag names used on this site.

It is also a good practice to create also [tag-excerpt and tag-wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-wikis/info) for the tag, if you create a new tag. If you are [below 20k](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) your edit to the tag-info will need approval in suggested edits review queue. But do not let this fact scare you away. Tag-excerpts and tag-wikis are important for using the tag correctly. If you are creating a tag, probably you do this with the intention to help organize questions on this site better. Explaining the intended usage in the tag-excerpt might help this goal.

Answer (score 7):

A user with 1000 or more points has the [Create Tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege. These user can create new tags simply by typing the name of the tag into the field where one adds the tags of a question, either when posting the question or via editing the question.

In case of doubt, it can be desirable to propose the tag in  [Tag management 2015](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015) for some prior discussion.

This thread is  also a way for newer users to propose a tag.

Comment: What if we don't have that many points?