# The [contradiction] tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I wonder what should be done with the [contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction) tag. Some time ago it has been [proposed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/8665#8665) to be deleted.
A possible worthwhile use of the tag could be using it for questions about the logic behind a proof by contradiction (e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957408) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916810)), instead of questions about a *particular* proof by contradiction. But perhaps that would make it a very localised tag.

> Shall we delete [contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction)?

I have suggested burninating [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20197/43288).

Comment: At least renaming it to [tag:proof-by-contradiction] IMO, if that's what the tag is about. Before reading the tag excerpt I thought it was a subtag of [tag:fake-proofs].

Comment: The tag is useless. *Proof.* Assume towards contradiction that it is useful, but this is a contradiction since the [tag:contradiction] tag is useless. QED. Drop mic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You assumed both the result and its negation, but you may only assume the negation in a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @PyRulez: He is begging the question, but that's doesn't mean the proof is incorrect, just that it is not useful since the result was already known _a priori_. For example, given the parallel postulate as an axiom I can prove the parallel postulate using contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [(proof-strategy)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-strategy) as the preferred synonym.

I don't think every nuance of a topic has to have a tag of its own; proof-strategy is quite narrow enough. There's no great need for a proof-by-contradiction tag.

Comment: ... and renaming to [tag:proof-by-contradiction] as suggested by Najib Idrissi.

Comment: Though it should be noted that not all [tag:contradiction] questions fit within [tag:proof-strategy], so perhaps we should first re-tag some of them.

Comment: I can see a notation question, which only really needs a notation tag (which it has already).

Comment: I think that before adding synonyms for that tag, the usage of the tag ([tag:proof-strategy]) should be clarified. It is rather unclear and often users use this tag for any question related to proof. See, for example, [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/tags-proof-strategy-and-proof-writing) and other posts linked to it for some discussion of this tag.