# Proposed tags *Lucas Sequences* and *basis*

Tags: discussion, tagging

I wondered if the tags *Lucas Sequences* and *Basis* might be of use?  I imagine these would be sub-tags of *sequences-and-series* and *linear-algebra*.

Comment: About the "basis" tag : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21091/can-we-delete-the-basis-tag

Comment: And regarding Lucas sequences : we already have tags for "sequences-and-series", "recurrence-relations" and "lucas-numbers". I don't think a tag for Lucas sequences would be very useful.

Comment: @ArnaudD. ok fair enough, makes sense. Bear in mind Lucas sequences aren't Lucas numbers so that tag would be wrong in most cases.

Comment: And a bit more specific version of basis tag was discussed quite recently: [Creation of a Hamel basis tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27880)

Comment: I've recently edited the tag info for [tag:lucas-numbers] based on that of Fibonacci sequence.  This tag can be used for questions on Lucas sequence.

Comment: @GNUSupporter "Lucas Sequence" is a poor choice of phrase because the sequence of "Lucas Numbers" is not a canonical name for the "Lucas Sequences".

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment.  Maybe I should take a rest from this site.

Comment: @GNUSupporter not at all. It sounds like we have lucas-numbers and Lucas Sequences are discussed sufficiently infrequently they can go under sequences-and-series.

Answer (score 5):

There are a total of [25 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22lucas+sequence%22+is%3Aquestion) containing the words "Lucas sequence", and more than half of them are actually talking about the Lucas numbers, which there's already a tag for.

Granted, many people don't know what a Lucas sequence is or even how to pronounce "Lucas", so they might be talking about Lucas sequences without calling them out by name. But if that's the case, then they're not going to be using the proposed tag, either.

And if both the lucas-sequences and lucas-numbers tags existed, then we'd have to sort out the extra confusion caused by people using one when referring to the other, too.

Comment: The problem you describe of mis-tagging of Lucas Numbers posts, sounds like it's caused by the lack of, and almost certainly would be solved by the creation of, the Lucas Sequences tag.

Comment: I don't mean that they're mis-tagged: I mean that the question contains the words "Lucas sequence" but is actually talking about the Lucas numbers, and not the more general class of sequences.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. How should I properly pronounce "Lucas sequence"?  #askingForAFriend

Comment: @hardmath Lucas was French, so if you're saying something more like "lew-CAH" than like "LOO-cuss", then you're basically there.

Comment: @MishaLavrov : like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD49VRT-rOU)?

Comment: @JohnMa I hope so. If we can't trust YouTube videos on pronouncing names, can we trust anyone?

Comment: In IPA symbol, I would pronounce [lyka] as usual, with the stress at the last syllable.