# Expectation tag error

Tags: support, bug, tagging, user-interface, user-profile

## Background

In [Expectation means average?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28381/expectation-means-average), I proposed to synonymize [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation) and [expected-values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expected-values).  A moderator has done this.

## Problem

When I view [my tag scores](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:290189+[expectation]) in my profile and clicked on [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation), I *can't* see any posts.

[image]
[image]

This is browser-independent and tag-specific, as I got the *same* problem across devices and browsers, but this only happens for [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation).

[image]

Perhaps I have to use SE's database to retrieve my [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expectation) questions?

Comment: I think this is not the expected result. :P

Comment: Best case, some time lag accounts for the tag attribution discrepancy.

Comment: @hardmath The tag synonym has been created for more than a month, and this problem still persists.  SE's open data updates every week, so I don't think that's a time lag problem.  Even if what you've said was true, that's bad UX that web developers won't desire.